# Problema Ionic estilos css

Tags: html, css, ionic

estoy intentando colocar un mapa con mapbox en Ionic y el problema es que tengo estilos css que colocan el mapa al 100% de la pantalla.
Pero el mapa me aparece solo como un recuadro, pero cuando habilito o deshabilito las herramientas de desarrollador este si toma el 100% de la pantalla

Este es mi tab2.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab 2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="mapa"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Y mi tab2.page.sccs

```
ion-content ion-toolbar {
  --background: translucent;
}
#mapa{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Aqui en modo responsive**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aqui en modo web**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aqui cuando habilito las herramientas de desarrollador**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: selecciona el **ion-content** luego el div y agrega las clases que te aparecen

Comment: puedes agregarle una clase a cada componente y de igual forma se tendria que modificar :)

Comment: Es mas un id te convendria incluso mas ya que en cuando a la jerarquia de los elementos en html un id tiene mas peso que cualquier otro elemento dentro de css

Answer (score 5):

Para que tu mapa ocupe toda la pantalla deberías hacer lo siguiente en el html:

```
<div class="mapa"></div>
```

Y en el css prueba a cambiar esto

```
.mapa{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Si esto no te funciona prueba a crear un archivo de css como estilos.css y a linkearlo con la pagina de html con:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
```

Después metes la regla de css que he puesto antes y te tendría que funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es añadir el siguiente CSS a el estilo de tu elemento HTML

```
sytle="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
```

Ten en cuenta que esta en porcentaje y por lo tanto ocupara toda la pagina, para mas información en medidas con CSS mira esta [web](https://www.hazunaweb.com/curso-de-css/unidades-de-medida/)